# Ruby: Remove all exclamation marks from sentence except at the end

Tags: regex, ruby

Working on a code war challenge to remove all exclamation marks from the string except for the end. So far I've played around with some regex and fortunately enough I haven't recieved any error messages so it at least recognises my code as a valid expression.

```
def remove(s)
s.gsub(/\s+/, "!")
end
```

Could I please get some input on how I can write this regex to remove "!" from everywhere else in the string but the end? If I could possibly also get a method without regex that will be superb as regex can be a tad confusing.

For reference this is what the tests should look like:

```
Test.describe("Basic tests") do
    Test.assert_equals(remove("Hi!"),"Hi!")
    Test.assert_equals(remove("Hi!!!"),"Hi!!!")
    Test.assert_equals(remove("!Hi"),"Hi")
    Test.assert_equals(remove("!Hi!"),"Hi!")
    Test.assert_equals(remove("Hi! Hi!"),"Hi Hi!")
    Test.assert_equals(remove("Hi"),"Hi")
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove all `!` except all those at the end of string with

```
s.gsub(/!(?!!*\z)/, "")
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/BmW5XQNMxaD9Ir) and a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/MDsQyT/1) (converted to PCRE to work with multiline string).

**Details**

- `!` - matches a `!` sign
- `(?!` - start of a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that matches a location not immediately followed with:

  - `!*` - zero or more `!` chars up to
  - `\z` -  the end of string
- `)` - end of the lookahead.

You may extend the regex to replace any punctuation char unless at the end of string:

```
s.gsub(/([[:punct:]])(?![[:punct:]]*\z)/, "")
```

where `[[:punct:]]` matches any punctuation char (can be replaced with `[\p{P}\p{S}]`).

Comment: this looks so confusing yet so clean. is there really no way of avoiding learning regex?? thanks for the detailed breakdown

Comment: @KobadaTech I think this is really a good case for a regex. You may always write your own parsing method, sure.

Answer (score 2):

Non regex: take the string except the last char, remove the exclamation marks from that, add the last char back on.

```
def remove(str)
  return "" if str.empty?  # defend against nil-errors
  str[0..-2].delete("!") + str[-1]
end
```